# How does yahoo calculate Growth Estimates

Tags: equities, estimation, yahoofinance

Does anyone know how yahoo calculates Growth Estimates for the Next 5 Years (per annum)? For example, I can see 12.64% for AAPL as reporetd in Yahoo finance in https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL.
[image]

Comment: I assume this is consensus analyst estimates.

Answer (score 4):

5 year forward estimates comes from Refinitiv IBES  (Institutional Broker Estimate System).  It will be the mean estimate from all the analyst that cover the stock  that report into IBES.  It’s used industry wide.

Comment: I searched this and couldn't find a location for the growth estimates on the web.